# laravel 5.4 showing blank view

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravel-5.4

I am sending data from the controller to a view (this is a single page web app) but view's input fields are showing nothing. When I use console.log I got this (screenshot attached). My question is how do I show this data in an input field of view?

[image: \enter image description here][1]]

Controller

```
public function edit(Request $request){
        $results = Student::where('id', '=', $request->id)->get();
        return $results;
    }
```

View

```
<form class="form_edit" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        @if(isset($results))
        @foreach ($results as $result)
            <input type="hidden" id="id">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="grn" value="{{$result->grn}}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="addItem" value="{{$result->first_name}}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{$result->last_name}}">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_delete" value="Delete">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_close" value="Cancel">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_update" value="Update">
        @endforeach
        @endif
    </form>
```

Comment: return view('your_view_folder.your_view_page', $results);  replace your return with this line

Comment: i think you forgot to return view

Comment: When I try to return view('your_view_folder.your_view_page', $results); then it give me this error. Undefined variable: students (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\sms1\resources\views\students.blade.php).

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the data to view in laravel like this

```
public function edit(Request $request){
        $results = Student::where('id', '=', $request->id)->get();
        return view('your_view_folder.your_view_page', ["results" => $results]);
    }
```

note : your not loading the view page

Comment: Applied your suggestion and it is giving this error. Undefined variable: students (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\sms1\resources\views\students.blade.php)

Comment: did you loaded your Student modal ? @Gohar

Comment: @JYoThI you need to pass array in view

Comment: Yes model is loaded in controller, as it is adding and deleting students too. Only edit has problem.

Comment: your model is student or students ? @AjayDeepakKumar

Comment: I think for Model you need to ask to @Gohar

Comment: your model is student or students ? @Gohar

Comment: Model is Student.

Comment: EXTREMELY SORRY GUYS. There was a variable $students. Now Undefined variable issue is solved. Now controller is like this. $results = Student::where('id', '=', $request->id)->get(); return view('students', compact('results')); But just seen through Inspect Elements that in view it is not going inside @if(isset($results)). On the other hand Ajax's console.log(data); is printing whole view's html in Console. I am not getting what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I could recommend. First of all you are searching for student by id which I would assume should return a single student and it is the primary key of student. Therefore you may want to use Student::find(); . Also you would probably want to build your queries for searching on the model or a abstract base model in which you could create basic searches that all the models that extend it could use. for instance:

```
abstract class BaseModel extends Eloquent{

protected $guarded = [
    'id'
];

public $primaryKey = 'id';

public $incrementing = false;

public function __construct($attributes = array())  {
    parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent
    $this->id = uniqid();

    return $this

}


public static function getObjectById($id){
    $class = get_called_class();
    $results = $class::find($id);
    return $results;

}

public static function getAllObjects(){
    $class = get_called_class();
    return $class::all();
}

}
```

then your student class:

```
 class Student extends Model
```

{

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name'
];
protected $table = "student";

public $incrementing = false;

/**
 * Student constructor.
 * @param array $attributes
 */
public function __construct($attributes = array())  {
    parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent
    // Your construct code.
    // TODO split string stuff to get the rest of the attributes.

    return $this;

}
```

}

then your controller:

```
    class StudentController extends Controller{
        public function getStudent(Request $request){
            $results = Student::getObjectById($request->id);
            return response()->json([
                 'results' => $results
            ]);

        }
    }
```

Your route/web.php:

```
    Route::get('/student', 'EnumController@getStudent');
```

I like using my own frontend so I may use ajax to complete the request:

```
     <body>
          <div class="container">
               <div id="student-list" class="well"></div>
          </div>
     </body>

     <script>
         $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '/student',
              success: function( data ) {
                  results = data.results;

                  console.log(results);

                  $.each(results, function(key, value){
                         $('#student-list').append('<div >' + value + '</option>');
                   });


               }
           });     
     </script>
```

Comment: There is some decent logic about this question here, however, `Student::find()->first();` will not work. `find()` does not return a collection, therefore you cannot call `->first()` on it, as `->first()` is part of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. Instead, `find` returns an instance of a `Iluminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, which does not have a `->first()`

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Right I guess I am not sure if he is searching by primary key or not. So I am not sure if he is trying to return a collection or a single object. I will edit it to remove ->first();

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question: To pass data into a view, you must `return` the view, as @JYoThl quite correctly advises. But the data should be passed in as an array with key / value pairs, or you will get an error. (See [Laravel 5.4 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views).)

So if, for example, the view file containing your form element were named "formView.blade.php" and it was located in the resources/views/ directory, you would modify your controller method as follows:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    $results = Student::where('id', '=', $request->id)->get();
    return view('formView', ['results' => $results]);
}
```

Or alternatively...

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    $results = Student::where('id', '=', $request->id)->get();
    return view('formView')->with('results', $results);
}
```

`$results` is now available in your view.

Comment: Applied your suggestion and it is giving this error. Undefined variable: students (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\sms1\resources\views\students.blade.php)

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are you, in D:\xampp\htdocs\sms1\resources\views\students.blade.php, using a variable $students? (If so, I don't see it in your code blocks above. You can use $results in the view or, for instance, $results[0]->last_name, but unless you add some additional code I can't see in the code blocks, you're not allowed to use a $students variable.) 2. The model you are using is named "Student", not "students"... but maybe it's not properly registered/aliased?

Comment: 1. This error is actually saying Undefined variable to the view parameter i.e. students (students.blade.php). I am not using students as a variable.
2. I think Model Student is working properly because it is adding new students and deleting students too.

Comment: In my experience, that error should mean you are using a variable `$students` somewhere in your view. Check the entire nested view structure: templates your view @extends; @yield sections your view uses; maybe an @include partial in the view that has or expects a 'students' parameter passed to it? Also, you could try renaming $results in the controller method to $students, replacing the `return` with `return view('formView', ['students' => $students]);`, changing all variables `$results` in the view to `$students` and see if the error disappears. Hope that helps.

Comment: EXTREMELY SORRY GUYS. There was a variable $students. Now Undefined variable issue is solved. Now controller is like this. $results = Student::where('id', '=', $request->id)->get(); return view('students', compact('results')); But just seen through Inspect Elements that in view it is not going inside @if(isset($results)). On the other hand Ajax's console.log(data); is printing whole view's html in Console. I am not getting what is wrong here.